# React useEffect prevent on initial mount

Tags: reactjs, redux-firestore

i have five a snapshot listener in useEffect and i have another call api  to  get data from firestore and update state
but I am facing a problem  is  every initial mount  all listener got called , my goal is i want to all listener called only when document changed
i tried with **useRef** it works but listener do not trigger

As you can see in the example below,  **onSnapshot** is printed during the initial mounted

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstMount.current) return;
    someFirestoreAPICall.onSnapshot((snap) => {
          //called every initial mount
    });
 someFirestoreAPICall.onSnapshot((snap) => {
          //called every initial mount
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstMount.current) {
      isFirstMount.current = false;
      return;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);

      let snap = await someFirestoreAPICall.get();

      setData(snap.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-surex?file=/src/Lists.js)

Comment: why five useEffect? Can't you write one useEffect

Comment: @SifatAmin i meant five listener inside useEffect

Comment: I often find it useful to use different useEffect blocks, as you can have different dependencies for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition inside your useEffect block as you are doing, I think. But perhaps `useState` would be more appropriate here than `useRef`.

eg:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(null)

useEffect(()=>{
    if (state) {
        // do something
    }
}, [state])
```

The useEffect will run on mount and every time you change the value of state, but code inside the condition will only run if you change the state to a truthy value.

Comment: can you suggest me an example with listen snapshot ?

Comment: where in my code it says `// do something` you can do whatever you like.

Comment: i know, i tried to put my listener inside condition but they don't trigger

Comment: You need to show in your example when you define the useRef (`isFirstMount`) and the `someFireStoreAPICall` ...this is not clear enough to understand.